# How to create a mapping from segmented memory in userland?

Tags: c++, c, memory, linux-kernel

In Linux, `mmap` can be used to create a mapping in the virtual address space of a process. One of its use cases is working with very large files. Unfortunately, it can only create a mapping for something that was already contiguous to start with: it accepts just one `offset` and `length`.

I'm looking for a solution to map several segments in memory to one contiguous address range. A user of this would be an NTFS driver running in user space which wants to present a contiguous address range for a file that has in fact been fragmented on disk. In my understanding, this is possible for drivers that run in the kernel, but I'm specifically looking for a solution in user space.

The solution should be C/C++. I've got no requirements in regard to kernel version. So far, the best approach that I could come up with is writing an iterator that knows how to jump from segment to segment, but I also want to interface with libraries that only accept a character array.

I hope this got my question across. Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, it can only create a mapping for something that was already contiguous to start with: it accepts just one `offset` and `length`.

It only accepts one `offset` and `length` at a time, you can call `mmap` more than once.

From [man 2 mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), note the `addr` argument:

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
           int fd, off_t offset);
```

Start by creating one large mapping (maybe `/dev/zero`, perhaps). Then, remap parts of that mapping how you will.  To remap, pass the start address to `addr` and use `MAP_FIXED`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The man page states "MAP_FIXED - Don't  interpret  addr  as  a hint: place the mapping at exactly that address.  _addr must be a multiple of the page size._". So it seems you cannot freely glue together any addresses you want. Or does this not apply anymore once the initial mmap has been created?

Comment: @delins: Note that `offset` also has to be a multiple of the page size. Basically, everything has to be a multiple of the page size. This reflects how the MMU on your processor works. So `mmap` lets you glue addresses together however you want... as long as those addresses are multiples of the page size.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The individual segments may have any size, including less than the page size (a theoretical minimum of 1 byte). A good idea regardless!

Comment: None architecture can map memory area less than a page size.